# What if I want to withdraw the referrals, after learning they took offers elsewhere?

Tags: communication, references, referral

I got offer from my company which I will work in post graduation. On the basis of this, several of my peers asked to be referred to my recruiter. I obliged and send an email to the recruiter with 4 referrals.

After I send the email, I found 2 of my referrals have already accepted offers from other companies. Should I tell my recruiter about it? If I say, will it reflect poorly on me?

Comment: You are not obligated to tell the recruiter that. Your 2 friends may not be 100% sure about the job offers that they already accepted. It could be that they accepted those 2 positions because they were the first offers  that they got right out of college, and they need a job very urgently to pay the bills, and the positions may not fit their long term career goals. So, they may be shopping around for better offers to fit their long term career goals.

Comment: If you tell the recruiters that, and the recruiter rejects your friends and tell your friends that the reason for the rejection is that you told him that your friends already accepted job offers elsewhere, then what do you think your friends would say to you ?

Comment: You gave the recruiter a name and a phone number. Everything beyond that is up to them. They will at some point call the person and be told “no”, that happens to them a gazillion times.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to withdraw the referrals. You just gave the recruiter a lead to a possible candidate; that does not imply that there candidate will be interested in working with them. They may already have accepted somewhere, they may prefer to work through their own channels, they may be talking a year off to hike the Appalachian Trail or do volunteer work, whatever. The recruiter will call them, they will say if they are or aren't interested, the process will do the right thing.

I would only actively withdraw my recommendation if I no longer thought that person was worth talking to, or if I was asked to do so, or if the other party had accepted a full written contract with committed salary and start date and so on.

Comment: I believe you missed the part where OPs friends specifically asked to be put their names through to the recruiter.

Comment: Corrected. Tnx.

Answer (score 5):

> After I send the email, I found 2 of my referrals have already accepted offers from other companies. Should I tell my recruiter about it? If I say, will it reflect poorly on me?

Yes, I suggest you tell your recruiter about this. No, it won't reflect poorly on you, in fact it will show that you care for the recruiter's time.

"Hey, about the people I referred, I am finding now that Joe and Marie may have already accepted offers elsewhere. Just wanted to give you that update".

Answer (score 1):

Email each of those two acquaintances you referred and ask them if you can tell your new employer that they accepted offers elsewhere.

This insures that you are not the cause of any miscommunication. If they do not reply within 48 hours, call those acquaintances directly.

> If I say, will it reflect poorly on me?

Yes, do not make a mistake, seek confirmation. This is an important matter.

If you made a mistake, or if one of your referrals lies and says that you misunderstood what they said, this could cause unnecessary drama.

Also, if those two already told your new company about it, then telling your new company something they already know would be kind of pointless anyway.